# How do I change the Exchange server name in my users mail profile?

Tags: exchange-2010

I need to change the server name for all my Exchange users, both servers are online so it should be a smooth transition, my question is how can I change the server name shown in the users mail profile? A script or utility would be ideal.

Thanks

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6deb2ac1ad.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6deb2ac1ad.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless its changed in the new version, you shouldn't need to change it.

- Close Outlook
- Move mailbox from old server to new server
- Leave the old server online
- Open Outlook, it should automagically detect the change.